# Subclassing in Objective C Runtime

Tags: c, nswindow, objective-c-runtime

I am attempting to implement a solution from [How to set canBecomeKeyWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776875/how-to-set-canbecomekeywindow) Into my native C application using Objective-C runtime (The app is already written with objective C Runtime). Is there a way to create a subclass purely in Objective-C Runtime?

Right now I just create `NSWindow` object but need to be able to create my own so I can override the function specified in that question.

```
objc_msgSend((id)objc_getClass("NSWindow"), sel_registerName("alloc"));
```

Comment: Are we sure that C tag applies to this question?

Comment: Yup this application is written in C using the Objective-C runtime, I figured it out though, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after a lot of code searching:

```
        // Subclass NSWindow with overridden function
        Class __NSWindow =
            objc_allocateClassPair(objc_getClass("NSWindow"), "__NSWindow", 0);
        class_addMethod(__NSWindow,
                        sel_registerName("canBecomeKeyWindow"),
                        (IMP)can_become_key_window_true, "B@:");
        objc_registerClassPair(__NSWindow);

        // Allocate a new __NSWindow
        window = objc_msgSend((id)__NSWindow, sel_registerName("alloc"));
```

And then `can_become_key_window_true` is defined as:

```
static bool can_become_key_window_true() {
    return true;
}
```

I use [objc_allocateClassPair](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418559-objc_allocateclasspair) to subclass the object and return a `Class` of that object. Then I use [class_addMethod](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418901-class_addmethod?language=objc) to override the method `canBecomeKeyWindow`. And finally use [objc_registerClassPair](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418603-objc_registerclasspair?language=objc) to register my new class before using it as I would a normal `NSWindow`.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `can_become_key_window_true` is slightly incorrect. According to the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective-c_runtime/imp?language=objc) the function should have at least two arguments: "self" and "_cmd". So the signature should be like:

```
static bool can_become_key_window_true(__unused id _self, __unused SEL _cmd) {
    return true;
}
```

You could also use `@encode` to construct the type encoding for the function.

```
char encoding[10]; // should be enough
snprintf(encoding, 10, "%s%s%s", @encode(BOOL), @encode(id), @encode(SEL));
```

... or you could get a method from `UIWindow` and get its type encoding like:

```
Method m = class_getInstanceMethod(objc_lookUpClass("UIWindow"), sel_getUid("canBecomeKeyWindow"));
const char *encoding = method_getTypeEncoding(m);
```

And as you might have noticed you could use `sel_getUid()` instead of `sel_registerName` as you expect this selector to be already registered by this time (because you are about to override an existing method).

To allocate a new instance you could use

```
window = class_createInstance(__UIWindow);
```

Comment: Interesting, my answer worked fine for me. I wonder why I didn't need the correct signature for `can_become_key_window()`

Comment: IMO the signature is such a "convention" for a caller and for the body of a function. So the caller knows how to pass arguments and the function knows how to "unpack" them. Technically you can cast any function to any signature and call it, passing any garbage as arguments. So if you do not use any arguments in function's body nothing terrible should happen because you just do not work with "garbage" data that you passed. But I guess it might depend on the architecture, on calling conventions and so on.